# Is it posible to use lamba with QDoubleSpinBox Value Changed to do somthing along with if condition?

Tags: python, lambda

Is it possible to use lambda in my below example code or is there any single line solution?
If possible how to do?
Below is example code:

```
self.total_spin.valueChanged.connect(self.valuechanged)
def valuechanged(self):
    if self.total_spin.value() != 0.00:
        self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100.00)
    else:
        self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(0.00)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code in one line with the lambda keyword:

```
self.total_spin.valueChanged.connect(lambda value: self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100 if value else 0))
```

Comment: I tried your line, It is not setting `self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100.00)` after value changed on `self.total_spin` and no error.

Comment: It is not working from first attempt. It is working if `self.total_spin` set more than 0 and again setting 0 then only working.  And i tried this code from your given reference code `self.total_spin.valueChanged.connect(lambda value: self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100.00 if value else 0.00))` working.

Comment: Please edit your answer and i need to accept this is your credit...

Comment: @user3030327 Got the if statement order wrong, my mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: Please find edited question. I added else statement also. Please edit answer. I hope my request is not bother you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could pass for example the new value directly as an argument.

```
self.total_spin.valueChanged.connect(lambda new_value: self.valuechanged(new_value))
def valuechanged(self, new_value):
    if new_value != 0.00:
        self.SpinBox_one.setMaximum(100.00)
```

Comment: I want to short my example scenario  as single line. But your answer is also have multiple lines and there is no deference between our both examples almost.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question.